# Scroll texture on Sprite in Unity for background scrolling effect, not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to achieve a scrolling background effect using a Sprite in a 2D Unity project.

I've seen this code being used on 3D objects with a MeshRenderer to achieve the effect but this does not seem to work on a Sprite with SpriteRenderer. Does anybody know why?

```
public class ScrollingTexture : MonoBehaviour {

  public float ScrollSpeed = -0.5f;
  private Vector2 _savedOffset;
  private Renderer _renderer;

  private void Start ()
  {
      _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
      _savedOffset = _renderer.material.mainTextureOffset;
  }

  private void Update() 
  {
      float x = Mathf.Repeat (Time.time * ScrollSpeed, 1);
      Vector2 offset = new Vector2(x, _savedOffset.y);
      _renderer.material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
  }

  private void OnDisable()
  {
      _renderer.material.mainTextureOffset = _savedOffset;
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
To get it to work properly I have added a new material as suggested and set its shader to Unlit/Transparent. I also had to make sure the Sprite itself had its Wrap Mode set to Repeat. I did not fix the Inspector Warning yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this warning in the inspector

[image]

I managed to get it scrolling by just creating a New Material and assigning it to the GameObject, then changing the Shader to Sprites/Diffuse.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I did what you said and also got it scrolling, but still with the same code, meaning it still shows the warning in the inspector. The texture looks dark though with shader set to Sprites/Diffuse, not with Sprites/Default, but then the texture doesn't scroll, and the scrolling is weird, it's like the right side (1 pixel wide line) of the texture is repeated until it starts over again. Did you change anything in the code?

Comment: I still get the warning aswell. It's darker here aswell, you could try some other shader, for example Unlit/Transparent doesnt seem to affect the brightness,and i dont get repetition.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Unlit/Transparent, then the texture looks normal, but I still get the weird 1 pixel wide repetition.